# How to fix my math code about series in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, math, series

I need to write a basic "for loop" that calculates the math problem i've written below. I have tried to write it, but i'm not sure if it is correct. 
Can you fix it, if there's anything wrong with it?

[image: \prod^{6}_{n=1} \sum^{10}_{m=2}(n^3+1)^{2m+1}]

(m=2 and n=1 is the limit inferior)

```
a=1
b=0

for n in range(1,7):
    for m in range(2,11):
        x=(n**3+1)**(2*m+1)
        b=b+x
    a=a*b
print(a)
```

Comment: Your mathematical expression is very unclear to me. Please write it in a different form. For example, you could use MathJax at [Mathematics Stack Exchange](http://math.stackexchange.com/), copy the graphic, and link to it. We could insert that graphic into your question. But your first two characters "∏6" are completely unclear. Is the "∏" a product symbol and the "6" a factor that multiplies the sum?

Comment: What makes you think it's incorrect? Technically, you can attempt this by hand, and compare the results.

Comment: @RoryDaulton with the code next to it, it's very straightforward for me to read: upper-case pi is a product, with the 6 the upper bound, and n=1 the starting point. Similar for upper-case sigma, with 10 upper bound and m=2 the starting point.

Comment: At a cursory glance it looks ok. Why aren't you sure? Did something bad happen when you ran it? Do you know what output you are expecting? Would some more print statements inside the loops help you see what happens inbetween?

Comment: Your `b` will increase endlessly, and not reset between completions of the inner loop. You may want to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `b` is not reset after each iteration so the sums are not correct. If you want to use loops, do this:

```
a=1

for n in range(1,7):
    b=0
    for m in range(2,11):
        b+=(n**3+1)**(2*m+1)
    a*=b
print(a)
```

If you want to be more concise, do this:

```
a=1
for n in range(1,7):
    a*=sum((n**3+1)**(2*m+1) for m in range(2,11))
print(a)
```